# Здравствуйте, при использовании NUITKA возникает ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x, mingw, mingw-w64, nuitka

При использовании команды `python -m nuitka --mingw64 --onefile main.py` ошибок не возникает.
Но если я использую `python -m nuitka --mingw64 --windows-disable-console --onefile main.py` то вылезает ошибка:

```
Nuitka-Options:INFO: Used command line options: --mingw64 --windows-disable-console --onefile main.py
Nuitka:INFO: Starting Python compilation with Nuitka '0.7.4' on Python '3.10' commercial None.
FATAL: __main__.py: can't open file 'main.py'.
```

PS. Пытался переустановить nuitka и mingw64 не помогало

Answer (score 0):

Спасло меня переустановка mingw-w64 вот тут -> https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).